# Possible to suspend via lan?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, suspend, lan

I've already set up wake on LAN (via WIFI local network) and I am able to wake my Ubuntu machine via local network (from Windows 7 laptop using WakeOnLan from Magick Packet).

Is there a way to **suspend on LAN** the same machine?

I hate going downstairs each time I finish remote LAN work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, via SSH. Set up `openssh-server` on your computer to proceed. Next, have a look at [this page](http://pifostap.org.ua/blog/2011/12/12/shutdown-dbus.html) to find the appropriate command to invoke the suspend. You could simply use `sudo pm-suspend`, however, this requires root priviliges.

Now, turn the suspend command into a Bash alias by adding the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias suspendnow='dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend'
```

Save, log out and back in again.

Now, if everything is set up correctly, you could run:

```
ssh user@computer -f 'suspendnow'
```

to initiate the suspend of your computer. Note, this might not work on a server, you'll have to use `sudo pm-suspend` instead of the fancy dbus method.

Comment: it's a local machine so I managed this via `putty` + `sudo pm-suspend`. thanks!